# External HDD for Games with an internal SSD?

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, gaming, usb-3

I have an SSD of 250GB 2.5" (SAMSUNGS EVO 850) and the laptop have 1TB hdd. The problem I am facing is which one to put on the sata slot. I am planning to put the ssd in the sata slot and then buy a USB 3 Adapter for the hdd and then install most of the game in hdd and other multimedia in the ssd. How will my game performance be in this case ? Is there any better option?

Comment: Get a bigger SSD drive. Your performance could be pretty bad trying to run games from external drive, even if it's USB 3.0, depends on the game. Some laptops have a HDD tray that be installed in place of the optical drive, what laptop?

Comment: Actually I will buy the laptop and this is the that is confusing me , I am trying between "Asus ROG GL552VW" and "Asus N551VW" , How can I tell for HDD tray in place of optical?